# How to check parameters on a shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Sometimes shapes would have parameters like a stoke or rounded corners, but once the shape is drawn, I can't find how to see or change these parameters. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I only have CS 5.1, but this is how I would do it:

To change the stroke of the shape and open up Layer > Layer Styles > Stroke.

As for the corner radius, it's probably easier to just redraw the shape. But you can adjust the handles/anchors using the Direct Selection Tool if you really want to.

Comment: ermm... you have an Appearance Panel in Photoshop? ;)

Comment: Guess I should read the tags closer :( Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can view and/or change stroke attributes of the shape on the upper `Options` panel when you select your shape with `Path Selection Tool (A)`.

You may also copy and paste fill and stroke of the shape by right-clicking on the shape layer name and selecting `Copy Shape Attributes`/`Paste Shape Attributes`

However there is now way to view or change the radius of the rounded corners after the shape has been created which I also find quite inconvenient...

Answer (score 0):

@Const right - there is now way oficially...

One working trick for rectangles with same color of fill and stroke - you can use layer style and control border radius with size of stroke.

For advanced vector editing use illustrator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are applied stroke in layer style you can see and modify the style. 
**Using script plugin we can edit and see the rounded corners radius parameters in photoshop.**
Here you can find the plugins.
http://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/
http://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/rounded-rectangle-radius-resizer/
Installation

Copy and paste plugins here "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Presets\Scripts".

Open Photoshop file , you can run the script from File->Scripts->Corner Editor and Rounded_Rectangle_Radius_Resizer open any one plugin see the parameters and modify.